# Applying a mask in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, mask, gaussian

I'm having problems applying a mask to an image after this process:

1] I create a mask in matlab using `roipoly`.

2] I convert it from a logical to a double so I can apply Gaussian blur.

3] I apply a Gaussian blur to the mask.

I then want to multiply an image to this mask so it 'cuts out' the area defined by the mask (but it should look blended due to the Gaussian blur). This is where the problem occurs. I get the following error:

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

The image dimensions are `480x640x3` while the mask dimensions are only `480x640`. How can I combine these images? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function blendedImage = BlendImages(pyr1, pyr2, mask, level)

maskImage = double(mask);
pyr1_mask = GaussianPyramid(maskImage, level);
pyr2_mask = GaussianPyramid(1 - mask, level);
pyr_combined = cell(level, 1);
for i=1:level
    % this is where the error is:
    pyr_combined{i} = (pyr1{i} .* pyr1_mask{i}) + (pyr2{i} .* pyr2_mask{i});
    figure; imshow(pyr_combined{i});
end

figure; imshow((pyr1_mask{level}));
```

Comment: Try to do it per channel individually.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the error part -

```
pyr_combined{i} = bsxfun(@times,pyr1{i},pyr1_mask{i}) + bsxfun(@times,pyr2{i},pyr2_mask{i});
```

BSXFUN might be faster than using REPMAT method used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806192/masking-an-rgb-image-with-binary-mask).